# Laravel 4 background-image: url

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to get the full path of my image to work across the board instead of using image/blah/blah on my page I have them working with the blade template engine

```
 {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css'); }}
 {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap-responsive.css'); }} 
 {{ HTML::style('css/style.css'); }}
 {{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js'); }}
```

But I am trying to use background-image for a menu bar

```
background-image: url(images/transparentBackground.png)
```

Is there a way to use Blade templates to get that image to load the full path?

If I use

```
background-image: url({{ HTML::script('images/transparentBackground.png'); }})
```

It doesnt work and returns errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, first of all, you'd want to use

```
url({{ URL::asset('images/transparentBackground.jpg') }})
```

instead of

```
`HTML::script()`.
```

That would work if you are using inline styles.

If you are trying to have blade parse a linked stylesheet however, that's just never going to work. Nor should it. In that case, you might want to look into using something like Sass and Compass. With the right configuration, you can have full paths to your images generated automatically.

Comment: that worked thanks! I was just having problems getting it to load on folders that were not in the public directory thats all

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your problem very well. Why do you need a full path? This is css. Images folder has to be near a css file.

In your case try `background-image: url(../images/transparentBackground.png)`

```
-- public (folder)
---- css/style.css
---- images/transparentBackground.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use helper functions [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers)

Here is an example of background-image using helper function

`background-image: url("{{ public_path('images/bg_invoice.jpg') }}");`

public_path is a helper function to the path of public folder in your Laravel app and images is the nested folder in public. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing inline styles (via the style="" attribute in the HTML tag, then what @Rogier suggested would work.

If you want to use blade to generate CSS then you could do it by creating a CSS controller and passing your variables through that to a blade template to render the CSS (remember to set the content-type header to text/css).

Answer (score 0):

HTML::image('url/to/image.jpg', 'alt text');

OR

CAN BE USED

```
img src="{{ URL::to_asset('url/to/image.jpg') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 5 just do this

```
style="background-image:url({{ asset('Images/jamb.jpg') }});"
```

And like @Khandad Niazi said its just for inline CSS